# Apple отказал в публикации из за отсутствия поддержки IPv6 - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iphone, appstore

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Я получил отказ от Элл на основании того, что приложение якобы не поддерживает `IPv6`. У меня данные в таблицу загружаются из `icloud`. Но я делал программу на `x-code` на стандартных настройках и рассчитывал, что поддержка всех актуальных типов сетей - это само собой разумеющееся. Как ни странно все функции полноценно работают при тестировании на телефоне, а в симуляторе нет. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как настроить поддержку для моего приложения. Заранее спасибо. 
`Eduardbond` на форуме.

Comment: проблема не в приложении, а в одном из сервисов, которые оно использует. попробуйте определить какой именно

Comment: Сервис iCloud. Проблема с симулятором устранилась, когда я залогинился в нем в icloud.  Но у комиссии все-равно проблема присутствует даже с залогиненным айклаудом. Не могу понять почему.

Comment: через любой прокси посмотрите все запросы, там есть что то через ipv4